# display custom field from inner blog in the main homepage of wordpress multisite

Tags: custom-field, multisite

I'm using wordpress MU network and I have the main site and all the inner blogs.
as people may know it is very hard in wordpress MU to make "relationship" between the main site and the inner blogs.

also there is not enough information and soutions on the web regarding wordpress MU unfortunately.
(also posted [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104886/wordpress-mu-display-post-thumbnails-from-sub-blogs-in-main-site-homepage?rq=1) question and no one ever responded)

anyway, in order to display some values from the inner blogs in the main site's homepage I had to use this plugin:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-sitewide-tags/
which does pretty nice work but not perfect.

anyway, what I am trying to accomplish is to create a simple custom field, use it in the post editor of one of the # inner # blogs and display the value in the main site's homepage..

does anyone know how to do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `switch_to_blog( $new_blog_id )`, use `get_post_meta($post_id, $key )` to get the value of the field, and run `restore_current_blog()` when you are done.

You could use a site option (`add_site_option($option, $value)`) and store the values you need in an array there in addition to the post meta field. This would save the rather expensive `switch_to_blog()` calls.

Comment: Hi @toscho, I will definitely try that and let you know how it went. Thanks a lot